# Printing a statement using threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to print a statement in Java using threads, where each thread should print part of the statement. However, following code does *not always* output statement in correct order.

```
class NewThread implements Runnable {
    String msg;
    Thread t;
    NewThread(String str) {
        t = new Thread(this);
        msg = str;
    }
    public void run() {
        PrintMsg(msg);
    }
    synchronized void PrintMsg(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }
        System.out.println(msg);
        notify();
    }
}
class ThreadDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        NewThread t1, t2, t3;
        t1 = new NewThread("Humphry Dumprey");
        t2 = new NewThread("went to the hill");
        t3 = new NewThread("to fetch a pail of water");
        t1.t.start();
        t2.t.start();
        t3.t.start();
        try {
            t1.t.join();
            t2.t.join();
            t3.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Main Thread Interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect problem with *inter-thread communication*.

Comment: Well, what does it do? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: Ummmmmm, waffles......

Comment: You can use `Thread.sleep(millis);` after starting each thread , though I guess its a bad idea.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot: It is not wise to use time based approach, since they are not deterministic.

Comment: @Doorknob: I want to wait a thread until it finishes writing a part of statement. It should be like this : Thread 1 prints "Humphry Dumprey" Thread 2 prints "went to the hill" Thread 3 prints "to fetch a pail of water" and these three threads should execute in sequence such that the statement gets printed in right sequence.

Comment: Yes, but what's wrong with the code you have now? What does it do?

Comment: The statement gets printed in a random order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in this method:

```
synchronized void PrintMsg(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
    try {
        wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }
    System.out.println(msg);
    notify();
}
```

The thread that call it are going to call `wait()` which causes them to wait indefinitely for someone to call `notify()`.  But there are no other calls to `notify()` so they all will stop there.

Also, because the method is `synchronized` each thread is also waiting on it's own `NewThread` instance.  I think you meant to have all threads waiting and notifying on the same object?

From comments:

> want to wait a thread until it finishes writing a part of statement. It should be like this : Thread 1 prints "Humphry Dumprey" Thread 2 prints "went to the hill" Thread 3 prints "to fetch a pail of water" and these three threads should execute in sequence such that the statement gets printed in right sequence.

I never understand these sorts of questions.  The whole point of threads are that the run asynchronously in parallel.  If you want them to print 3 things in a row then 1 thread should be used instead.

If you need to do this for some assignment then there a couple different ways you can do it.

- Each thread could synchronize on the same `AtomicInteger`.  Thread #1 would do its print if the integer was 1, thread #2 when it is 2, ....  You could pass in the order as a `value` field to the `NewThread` constructor.  After they print they values they increment the integer and notifyAll().

  ```
  static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(1);
  ...
  synchronized (counter) {
      // looping like this is always recommended
      while (counter.get() != value) {
         counter.wait();
      }
      System.out.println(...);
      counter.incrementAndGet();
      counter.notifyAll();
  }
  ```
- You could use 2 `CountdownLatch` so thread #2 calls `countDown1.await();` and thread #3 waits for `countDown2.await();`.  Then after thread #1 prints its message it calls `countDown1.countDown()` and after thread #2 prints its message it calls `countDown2.countDown()`.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out the problem. How can I correct it? Or should I try to re-write the whole method?

Comment: Depends on what you want to accomplish @TanaySoni.  How do you want the threads to interact?  When do you want the threads to wait?  When do you want them to notify another thread?

Comment: In terms of waiting and notifying on the same object, you can pass in a `Object lock` object that they all synchronize one maybe.  Or define a `static final Object lock = new Object()` static object instead.

Comment: Maybe you waiting each thread to wait for a second instead of forever?  `wait(1000)`?

Comment: I want to wait a thread until it finishes writing a part of statement. It should be like this : Thread 1 prints "Humphry Dumprey" Thread 2 prints "went to the hill" Thread 3 prints "to fetch a pail of water" and these three threads should execute in sequence such that the statement gets printed in right sequence.